# How to limit image/icon request time?

Tags: image, browser, web-applications, icons

I've an application that fails to get a favicon.ico.

```
(failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

The issue is that it slows down the screen page upload:
[image]

I wonder if there is a way to limit the time (currently it takes 1.6 min connection phase until the connection error).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to control the timeout (by default, 8000)

```
export async function fetchWithTimeout(resource, options = {}) {
  const { timeout = 8000 } = options;
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const timeOut = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), timeout);
  const response = await fetch(resource, {
    ...options,
    signal: controller.signal
  });
  clearTimeout(timeOut);
  return response;
}
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
const response = await fetchWithTimeout('/items', {
  timeout: 10000
});

const data = await response.json();

...
```

I hope I've helped you
Have a nice day!